# how read date from server in Android Studio sdk23 and higer

Tags: java, android

i use by code Under for get date by formate jsone in eclips but this not working in android stadio 1.5 by sdk 23 
**Please help me**
under clase i use for conect server in eclips and working i need sample like this for Android stadio by sdk 23 and higher

```
package com.example.servicshareandread;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.widget.Toast;


public class Webservice {

    public static String readUrl(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);

            if (params != null) {
                method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);

            InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

            return result;
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            return builder.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

i use class Webservice by under coode

```
public void loadsharepoint()
{
     gotomap=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imggomaptab2);
     listshare=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listlocationsharetab2);
     String StrWeb = Webservice.readUrl("http://gorab.ir/map/search.php", null);
     String Temp = "";

     try {
         JSONArray list = new JSONArray(StrWeb);
         maylocationget=new ArrayList<StructTest>();
         maylocationget.clear();
         for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++)
         {
             StructTest record=new StructTest();

             JSONObject obj1 = list.getJSONObject(i);
             record.id = obj1.getInt("id");
             record.gid = obj1.getInt("gid");
             record. lat= obj1.getDouble("lat");
             record.longg = obj1.getDouble("long");
             record.title =CodeAndDecode.deCoder64(obj1.getString("title"));
             record.discription =CodeAndDecode.deCoder64( obj1.getString("discription"));
             record.addres = CodeAndDecode.deCoder64(obj1.getString("addrestiping"));


             maylocationget.add(record);
         }

         G.pepelerecord.clear();
         for (int i = 0; i < maylocationget.size(); i++) {
             G.pepelerecord.add(maylocationget.get(i));
         }
         adapterget = new AdapterTest2(G.pepelerecord);
         listshare.setAdapter(adapterget);
     }
     catch (JSONException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

i need help...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, "this not working" doesn't tell us anything about what fails. Does the code not compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it just give the wrong data? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Show your logcat please

Answer (score 0):

Add your gradle dependencies `compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'`
and add code below in your activity. You can find [here](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) more about Android Asynchronous Http Client library.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get("your_url", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        private ProgressDialog progressCircle;

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            progressCircle = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressCircle.setCancelable(true);
            progressCircle.setMessage("Wait ...");
            progressCircle.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressCircle.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
            progressCircle.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
            int lengthJSONArray = response.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthJSONArray; i++) {
                try {
                    StructTest record=new StructTest();

                    JSONObject obj1 = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    record.id = obj1.getInt("id");
                    record.gid = obj1.getInt("gid");
                    record. lat= obj1.getDouble("lat");
                    record.longg = obj1.getDouble("long");
                    record.title =CodeAndDecode.deCoder64(obj1.getString("title"));
                    record.discription =CodeAndDecode.deCoder64( obj1.getString("discription"));
                    record.addres = CodeAndDecode.deCoder64(obj1.getString("addrestiping"));
                    maylocationget.add(record);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use that library with Android API 23 and higher

Comment: If you want to use native android library visit [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: Thank you for for your answer but compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9' dont synce ?

Comment: i test this qustion i have one error for @overwrite under code   `code` @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                int lengthJSONArray = response.length();
            } `code`

Comment: Can you write your JSON data

Comment: delete onSuccess method and than Override again by Ctrl+O combination

Comment: Thank you for the same thing that you said the problem was solved thanks